# how to write it in efficient way

Tags: python, python-3.x

Accept four integers as input and write a program to print these integers in non-decreasing order.

The input will be four integers in four lines. The output should be a single line with all the integers separated by a single space in non-decreasing order.

Note: There is no space after the fourth integer.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())

if (a<=b and a<=c and a<=d):
    if (b<=c and b<=d):
        if(c<=d):
            print(a,b,c,d)
        else:
            print(a,b,d,c)
    elif(c<=b and c<=d):
        if(b<=d):
            print(a,c,b,d)
        else:
            print(a,c,d,b)
    else:
        if(b<=c):
            print(a,d,b,c)
        else:
            print(a,d,c,b)
elif(b<=a and b<=c and b<=d):
    if(a<=c and a<=d):
        if(c<=d):
            print(b,a,c,d)
        else:
            print(b,a,d,c)
    elif(c<=a and c<=d):
        if(a<=d):
            print(b,c,a,d)
        else:
            print(b,c,d,a)
    else:
        if(a<=c):
            print(b,d,a,c)
        else:
            print(b,d,c,a)
elif(c<=a and c<=b and c<=d):
    if(a<=b and a<=d):
        if(a<=d):
            print(c,a,b,d)
        else:
            print(c,a,d,b)
    elif(b<=a and b<=d):
        if(a<=d):
            print(c,b,a,d)
        else:
            print(c,b,d,a)
    else:
        if(a<=b):
            print(c,d,a,b)
        else:
            print(c,d,b,a)
else:
    if(a<=b and a<=c):
        if(b<=c):
            print(d,a.b,c)
        else:
            print(d,a,c,b)
    elif(b<=a and b<=c):
        if(a<=c):
            print(d,b,a,c)
        else:
            print(d,b,c,a)
    else:
        if(a<=b):
            print(d,c,a,b)
        else:
            print(d,c,b,a)
```

Comment: Put them in a list and sort it?

Comment: Is this a working code? In case this works, it will be better to post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: make a list of integers. don't keep them in 4 variables. after that, the whole code can be greatly simplified

Comment: @all suggesting using built-in functions to sort - most likely, this is assignment and OP is restricted to use built-in `sort` \ `sorted` function (which he must state clearly, of course)

Comment: `print(sorted(map(int,(input(),input(),input(),input()))))`

Comment: @buran the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I didn't say to post it verbatim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(" ".join(str(i) for i in sorted([a, b, c, d])))
```

or

```
print(" ".join(map(str, sorted([a, b, c, d]))))
```

Answer (score 2):

if you input in one line space seperated integers

```py
sorted(list(map(int, input().split())))
```

if you input each integer in new line

```py
sorted([int(input()) for _ in range(4)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Enter the numbers separated by comma ','")
numbers=input() #getting the numbers in single line
numbers=numbers.split(",") #seprating the numbers
numbers=map(int,numbers) #getting the integer values
numbers=list(numbers) #converting to list
numbers.sort() #sorting the number in increasing order
print(numbers)
```

you can also use this:

```
print("Enter the numbers separated by space")
numbers=input() #getting the numbers in single line
numbers=numbers.split() #seprating the numbers
numbers=map(int,numbers) #getting the integer values
numbers=list(numbers) #converting to list
numbers.sort() #sorting the number in increasing order
print(numbers)
```